# PHP undefined query params

Tags: php

Im using ajax to pass params through a post. Pretty much my issue is that when i recieve the params in PHP if i do a **isset($_POST['param'])** it returns true and if i echo the param it displays **undefined**. The param im passing through ajax is not set which is correct in this case. The idea would be when i check if the param is set for it to return false if it is undefined, however this isnt happening. Any specific reasons as to why this might be?

```
$param= $_POST['param'];

$concat = array();
if(!empty($param) && isset($param)){ $concat[] = "param= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($param) . "'"; }
```

The above is my actual code ive done echos on the original **$_POST['param'];** and also on **$param**
 to see if this was the problem but it results the same. the echos ive done are of the actual param/variable and of the result of isset on these two.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/update.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: "param=" + param,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    });
```

param is defined above but in this specific case is not being set to anything it remains empty, passing an empty var.

Comment: `undefined` would be a string. Most likely thing is that you've got JavaScript that's sending an incorrect variable.

Comment: is this a known issue where the params that are passed and not set get set automatically to "undefined" as text? or...?

Comment: minitech is probably right on this: your Javascript is probably posting the actual string "undefined" to your page. It's probably not a PHP thing.

Comment: well i just found a solution pretty much setting the var param = ""; that way its not undefined and an empty string instead...

Comment: Just did the test using Firebug: When concatenating an `undefined` varibale with a string, you end up concatenating the string `"undefined"` instead of an empty string.